# Generate an HTML directory tree in Python

Tags: python, html, tree, directory

does anyone know of a way I can turn a directory path into a tree as follows (using Python 2.7)...

```
<div>
    <p class="toggle">item one</p>
    <div class="child">

        <p>contained</p>

        <p class="toggle">item</p>
        <div class="child" hidden="true">
            <p>inner</p>
        </div>

        <p class="toggle">item</p>
        <div class="child" hidden="true">
            <p>inner</p>

            <p class="toggle">wow</p>
            <div class="child" hidden="true">
                <p>waaay down</p>
                <p>somefile.py</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <p class="toggle">item</p>
        <div class="child" hidden="true">
            <p>inner</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**
the directory that would create the above output would look like this...

```
item one
-contained
-item
--inner
-item
--inner
--wow
---waaay down
---somefile.py
-item
--inner
```

Directories need to have the "toggle" class, and should be followed by a div containing the contents of that directory.

If anyone can figure this out, that would be great, thanks! I've been trying to figure this out for ages.

Comment: You should edit this question to show the input directory structure to go along with your output so that it's clear exactly what the program needs to do.

Comment: @mVChr thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

So... I figured it out! Recursive functions are the answer. The code is below

```
def generate_tree(path, html=""):
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        rel = path + "/" + file
        if os.path.isdir(rel):
            html += "<p class='toggle'>%s</p><div class='child' hidden='true'>" % (file)
            html += generate_tree(rel)
            html += "</div>"
        else:
            html += "<p>%s</p>" % (file)
    return html
```

Comment: Isn't "file" supposed to be a reserved keyword in python?

Comment: Also, the third line can be replaced with this to make it more cross-platform friendly:

rel = os.path.join(folder, filename)