# Django insert html code from function into template

Tags: python, django

I have a python function edited from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113929/generate-an-html-directory-tree-in-python), this creates an html code to display the images in a folder and it works fine ( I run it independently and copy paste the code in the template ) but now I want to make it inside Django so I create a templatetag but I only get plain text.

```
from django import template
import os 
from pathlib import Path

register = template.Library() 

@register.simple_tag
def generate_tree():
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        rel = path + "/" + file
        if os.path.isdir(rel):
            html += """<button type="button" class="collapsible">%s</button>"""% (file)
            html +='<div class="content">'
            html += generate_tree(rel)
            html += '</div>'
        else:
            html +='<div class="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-stretch"> <picture>'
            x=str(rel)[38:]
            html += """<img src="{% static "%s" """% ('% s',x)
            html += """%} " class="lazy card-img-top" >"""
            html +='</picture> </div>'
    return html
```

this is how i call my function in the html file:

```
{% load static html_tags %}
{% generate_tree 'path' %}
```

and this is a portion of the plain text i get

[image]

any ideas on how can I get the text like html code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in this post [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51986727/django-filters-to-return-html-that-will-be-rendered-in-the-template). all i needed to do was to import `mark_safe` and use it the function

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django import template
import os 
from pathlib import Path

register = template.Library() 

@register.simple_tag
def generate_tree():
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        rel = path + "/" + file
        if os.path.isdir(rel):
            html += """<button type="button" class="collapsible">%s</button>"""% (file)
            html +='<div class="content">'
            html += generate_tree(rel)
            html += '</div>'
        else:
            html +='<div class="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-stretch"> <picture>'
            x=str(rel)[38:]
            html += """<img src="{% static "%s" """% ('% s',x)
            html += """%} " class="lazy card-img-top" >"""
            html +='</picture> </div>'
    return mark_safe(html)
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure you use like this {{ text|safe }} in your template.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Actually it returns a string value so look up for a attribut or js function that will remove the strings